# Document Library with required field and comments

Tags: document-library

I am tasked with building SharePoint site that will hold documents, so decided to build a Document Library. However, the two other requirements are 1) tag with meta data the category that the doc falls into, and make sure there are comments.

Adding a site column to the document is easy. However, when the user creates a New document [we are using SharePoint online], Word on line is opened and they are never prompted to enter something in the category field.

They can add it when they return to SharePoint via the quick edit.

However, another requirement is to have a view for each category. This creates a real problem because if the user is in a view that only shows docs with category = "duck", the just saved document will NOT appear in the view. This would be a horrible user interface design.

I have versioning turned on, so users can comment on different versions, but I only see the most recent comments in the view.

I wonder if it would be better to make a list and add a rich text field or maybe attachments to the form. But I was told that attachments won't be indexed.

I would think this would be a pretty common request - documents with a field for categorization and comments.